# Metrics of change between vector datasets

Tags: vector, geometry, spatial-statistics, statistics

I have an old and a new set of parcel data which I'm looking to compare. I'm looking to compare changes in individual parcel geometries, so boundary/corner adjustment. Currently each parcel we have has a unique ID which is updated when it is subdivided or merged, so divisions/mergers are known and there are no other attributes to change.

Are there any standard metrics to measure the changes between each pair of parcels? Ideally I'd like to compile a report over a region and report on a moving average of change.

Comment: Are you using a particular GIS software to try and do this?

Comment: @PolyGeo None in mind really. Ideally we were looking to script the process long term, and I'm pretty biased towards Python, so I'm leaning towards QGIS / ArcMap, but I'd be just as happy to do it directly against the database. I don't imagine the implementation will be too hard (famous last words), more wondering if there's an accepted standard.

Comment: The [Data Comparison toolset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000003000000) is worth being aware of.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is parcel fabrics, and the [reports generated from adjustments](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Understanding_the_adjustment_summary/00wp00000016000000/). Followed closely by PolyGeo's suggestion. But I don't fully understand what change you're looking at - actual geometry changes? Ones that affect all parcels, or just figuring out which parcels did change? What is a change - a division/merger, boundary/corner adjustment, difference in attributes (guessing not based on the geometry tag), and or all?

Comment: Thanks @ChrisW - the adjustment report looks pretty well what I'm after, as I'm really only interested in changes to existing geometries (I've updated the question above to hopefully reflect that).